# ClassNotFoundException when using applet with Telerik controls

Tags: java, asp.net, applet, telerik, classnotfoundexception

First of all I am a `dotnet` developer and don't know anything about java. I am using a `java applet` in my **asp.net** application. basically this plugin is used for `uploading` folders which is not supported without using a plugin. I also have some `telerik` controls being used in one of my other pages. the problem is that when i try to run the page, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` in java.

I think this has got something to do with the `telerik` configurations in my `web.config` file

When I use the same `applet` in a different application which does not have any telerik controls or settings in the config, the applet works fine.

If anybody else has come across this issue or if you can tell me where I am going wrong, it would be really helpful.

Here's what I have in my aspx page.

```html
 <applet width="200" height="30"
    codebase="assets/applet"
    id="PGatewayApplet"
    name="PGatewayApplet"
    code="com.gatewaytest.pgateway.applet.PGatewayApplet.class"
    archive="PGatewayApplet.jar,dcm4che-core-2.0.22.jar,log4j-1.2.13.jar,slf4j-api-1.5.0.jar,slf4j-log4j12-1.5.0.jar">
    <param name="mayscript" value="yes" />
    <param name="Mode" value="FileUpload" />
    <ASP:PLACEHOLDER ID="ExtraAppletParams" RUNAT="server"></ASP:PLACEHOLDER>
</applet>
```

I don't have the code for this applet.
this same thing works fine in another asp.net application which does not have any telerik controls in it.

Comment: Without code its difficult to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I found that the `RadCompression` key in my `web.config` file was causing the issue. 
here's the key

```
<add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
```

I commented this in the config file and the `applet` started working.

Hope this helps the others.